# Reverting the vim source command

Tags: vimrc

I know i can load a new or reload a vimrc file with the `:source` command. But is there a reverse to this? Because every source only adds to vim.

For example. if I would load a vimrc file to map F5 to a certain action. would i be able to unload this binding? And what about custom function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on Unix & Linux.

Comment: You could probably save a session, then source your files. To restore previous settings, close vim and restart, loading the session.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the Tim Pope's plugin [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease), it has a `Disarm` command. I think it's the closest I know for your issue.

You can also want to create a custom source function that keep track of everything that has been added from the `source` command.